# Posting form to a hidden iframe in Android browser

Tags: android, html, iframe

I just noticed that one of the things that keep working in browsers on PC, does not work on an Android browser.

I want to POST a form to a hidden iframe. This is basically to initiate a file download after verifying user credentials.

```
<form method="post" action='/downloader.php' target="hiddenframe">
    ....
    ......
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>

<iframe name="hiddenframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

This doesn't work on Android browsers. I suppose I should be concerned of the iframe. What should I take care of or what alternatives I have to make this work?

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: iframe is not working android inbuid browser my app same issue how can resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Android handles frames, plus different Android roms use different browsers.

What I do know is that as of HTML5 frames are deprecated, therefore not a very good practise. If not anything you are going to have more and more compatibility issues with new browsers in the future.

Why don't you do the request on the same page? If the downloader.php has the proper headers the download process should start without breaking or changing the current page at all.

Comment: Good suggestion. I was not confident enough to trust the headers that do not change the current page. A bit more of learning now, I hope I could do it correctly. Thank you.

Comment: You can trust the headers, it's browser's default behaviour. It is really engough to set just content type and content disposition. Example: `Content-Type: image/jpeg`, `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="yourfile.jpg";`. A good practise is to pass the filesize as well `Content-Length: ...` in bytes. Thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 2):

check this notes about using iframe in Android:

[dose apple and Android Browsers support Iframe??](http://forums.asp.net/t/1763307.aspx/1?dose%20apple%20and%20Android%20Browsers%20support%20Iframe%20)

I hope this helps you.