# iframe tag not working android inbuild browser?

Tags: html, browser

I am working on a cross platform mobile application using phonegap (html,javascript)
problem is selected item related image not display in iframe and this image display another page please see below code

```
function onchangeevent(mySelect)
{
PageIndex2=mySelect.selectedIndex;
{
if 
(
mySelect.options[PageIndex2].value != "none"
)
{
frames['iframe2'].location.href = mySelect.options[PageIndex2].value;
}

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
  <p><select NAME="selectimage" SIZE="1" onChange="onchangeevent(this.form.selectimage)">
    <option VALUE="none" SELECTED>Select a page and go</option>
    <option VALUE="ic_launcher.png">one</option>
     <option VALUE="icon.png">two</option>
  </select> </p>
  <p>
  <IFRAME NAME="iframe2" frameborder="3" ALIGN="top" HEIGHT="100%" WIDTH="95%" HSPACE="10" VSPACE="10" align="middle"></IFRAME>
 </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

iframe  tag  not working android inbuild browser how can resolve the issue ?
please tell any alternative tags supported all browsers
Thank In Advance 
bobgally

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in a previous question in here [Posting form to a hidden iframe in Android browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342872/posting-form-to-a-hidden-iframe-in-android-browser/9221898#9221898)

iframes are not going to be supported in future browsers / standarts.

Instead, create an image tag and update it's SRC.

```
function onchangeevent(mySelect)
{
PageIndex2=mySelect.selectedIndex;
{
if 
(
mySelect.options[PageIndex2].value != "none"
)
{
document.getElementById('myimage').src = mySelect.options[PageIndex2].value;
}

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form">
  <p><select NAME="selectimage" SIZE="1" onChange="onchangeevent(this.form.selectimage)">
    <option VALUE="none" SELECTED>Select a page and go</option>
    <option VALUE="ic_launcher.png">one</option>
     <option VALUE="icon.png">two</option>
  </select> </p>
  <p>
  <img src="about:blank" id="myimage" alt="" />
 </p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```